# Wrong Date format determined by Angular

Tags: angular, date-formatting, date-pipe

I have been working with Angular 5 to show a timeline. The start and end dates are stored in DB sent from the back-end via REST.

I am getting the dates in the following format.

Start:  02-12-2019 11:26

End:  13-12-2019 13:14

As I need to convert this date to a given format, *'dd-MM-yy'* I tried using datepipe and I was getting Invalid pipe argument error for the second date. -> `"InvalidPipeArgument: '13-12-2019 13:14' for pipe 'DatePipe'"`

Then I tried to print the dates using

```
Date startDate = new Date(startDateIn);
Date endDate = new Date (endDateIn);
```

Output:

```
Start Date:  Tue Feb 12 2019 11:26:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
End Date:  Invalid Date
```

Is there any way to make Angular know that the input date is in 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm' format?

Comment: can you provide us with a stackblitz and your error :) ?

Comment: I have not used it yet. I will try.

Comment: because `MM-DD-YYYY` default format for Javascript, you have to format it manually!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gjuet
You can find the Stackblitz here. I have tried to reproduce this error. I am getting the right date for the first input string, but there is an error with second one.
Also while using the html inline date pipe I am getting an output for the first date, though it is not what I want. No output for the second date there.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale And how do I do that?

Comment: @VishnuSoman Check the posted answer

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses `MM/DD/YYYY` format as default, so when you are using:

```
02-12-2019 // This works but with invalid date - 12 Feb 2019
```

and

```
13-12-2019 13:14  // This doesnot because there is no 13 month
```

What you can do:

Use below function to change the format of the date:

```
changeDateFormat(date: string) {
  var dateParts = date.substring(0, 10).split("-");
  var ddMMYYYYDate = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]);
  return ddMMYYYYDate;
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjt8pk-wz3mto)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have startDate and endDate as global variable.

```
  startDate: Date = new Date();

  endDate: Date = new Date();
```

// define constructor as

```
constructor(private _datePipe: DatePipe)
```

now in your local method.

```
var start= "02-12-2019 11:26";
var end="12-13-2019 11:26";      

this.startDate = <Date>(this._datePipe.transform(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as any);
   this.endDate = <Date>(this._datePipe.transform(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as any);
```

// do your stuff

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gjuet
You can find the Stackblitz here. I have tried to reproduce this error. I am getting the right date for the first input string, but there is an error with second one.
Also while using the html inline date pipe I am getting an output for the first date, though it is not what I want. No output for the second date there.

Comment: It will work, but with wrong date. The date that comes from back-end is Dec 2nd 2019 and 'mm-dd-yy' will give February 12th 2019

Comment: @VishnuSoman Have you tried the posted answer? Does it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As the all mentionned above you need to format the date due to Javascript formatting your date on the wrong way, now he made a mistake.

You should us that method, but add the **+** in front of the dateParts element to convert them from string to number :)

```
changeDateFormat(date: string) {
  var dateParts = date.substring(0, 10).split("-");
  var ddMMYYYYDate = new Date(+dateParts[2], +dateParts[1] - 1,+dateParts[0]);
  return ddMMYYYYDate;
}
```